# Crash with instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Tags: objective-c, ios, debugging, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm trying to get a UISplitViewController to work using a storyboard, but when I try to instantiate my master ViewController my app crashes with a cryptic EXC_BAD_ACCESS and a disassembly.

I have a property, `splitNavVc` on my subclass of UISplitViewController, in my storyboard I have the setup below. `splitNavVc` is on the left hand side and is a subclass of UINavigationController. The problem is, after trying to instantiate the splitNavVc when the view loads, the app crashes. To instantiate it, I'm using

```
if(!detailVc){
    detailVc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailVc"];   
}
if(!splitNavVc){
    splitNavVc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SplitMenu"];// crash
}
[self setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:splitNavVc, detailVc, nil]];
```

Is there any way I can track down the cause of the exception? `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` isn't particularly descriptive.

[image: Storyboard layout]

There's no stack trace dumped to the console (lldb), but this is the error:
[image]

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bizarrely, this seemed to stop happening when I switched the debugger in XCode from LLDB to GDB. I'm using LLVM as the compiler if that makes a difference.

Comment: This exact thing has happend to me as well. I've switched back to LLDB again and it continues to work. very very annoying.

Comment: try cleaning targets once in a while