# instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier crashes app

Tags: ios5, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I am trying to instantiate a ViewController defined in MainStoryBoard.storyboard using the code snippet shown in the pic below. I also assigned an identifier to the controller but app crashed with the error shown in pic saying "Storyboard doesn't contain a controller with identifier masterViewController" although you can clearly see in pic that its there.
Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Error Screen]
Just so you know, following solution didn't work for me: [Crash with instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367715/crash-with-instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier)

Below is the snapshot that confirms that the storyboard object is same that is retrieved from viewcontroller and used to instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifer:. [image: Storyboard obj same]
**SITUATION DESCRIPTION**: I am trying to develop a custom SplitViewController (subclassed from UIViewController). This UIViewController is purely programmatic i.e. not based on IBInterface layout. However for its children i.e MasterViewController and DetailViewController I have made layouts in IBInterface. Now I am retrieving a UIStoryboard object in SplitViewController (purely programatic one) and passing it to a utility class shown here in the first pic that uses it to instantiate MasterViewController based on a layout in the Storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, looks like if should work.

Try this:

- Clean project and rebuild
- Check if `storyboard` contains an instance of the correct storyboard

---

Fix by shaffooo (from comments below)

> I rebuilt my storyboard and it fixed the issue I was having.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used storyboard.DebugDescription to confirm that the same storyboard object is used for instantiating the viewcontroller that was retrieved from within the splitviewcontroller (custom UIViewController), please see the picture in edit of question. Here is the code for that `UIStoryboard * storybd = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryBoard" bundle:nil];`. One thing I want to mention is that the viewController in which i am retrieving the storyboard object is designed programmatically and doesnt have a storyboard layout. Can that be a problem?.

Comment: Its actually a viewcontroller that I am trying to use as container viewcontroller and the viewcontroller I am trying to instantiate does have a storyboard layout. please let me know if you not clear.

Comment: Apparently I have no idea... One thing you can check is if the Indentifier 'masterViewController' in the Storyboard may contain a Space at the end like 'masterViewController '. This could cause the error

Comment: hmmm I checked identifier name is correct still not working. Thanks anyways.

Comment: What about if you try to access it e.g. from your app delegate - just for testing. [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryBoard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"masterViewController"] - does this work?

Comment: So there must be a general problem with your storyboard. There are only two options. First, your application tries to find the controller in the wrong storyboard (if you have more than one). Second, your storyboard is broken and I suggest you to create a new one.

Comment: First option is not applicable because its the only Storyboard. I will try the second one as it sounds reasonable though frustrating to rebuild other viewcontrollers layouts too. I will get back to you soon. Thanks

Comment: Before rebuilding everything you can try to rebuild just the broken controller. another option is to create a simple empty viewcontroller, name its identifier 'test' and try to instantiate that one.

Comment: Yah even empty controller with identifier 'test' failed. Storyboard might be broken. Some thing is really wrong. Will rebuild it and see what happens.

Comment: I rebuilt my storyboard and it fixed the issue I was having. Its really strange and frustrating. I have marked your answer right but I would really like it if somebody direct me to some link that describes reasons for storyboard to break. Also it would be nice if you can edit your answer and write the solution you suggested so that it can be helpful for people in future without reading all these comments. thanks

Comment: maybe you can send a copy of your storyboard to apple with a note to the bug

Answer (score 1):

try to write the same name of your ViewController class into 'StoryBoard ID' in IB. Then edit the argument of your instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier method with same string:

yourVCName *startingViewController = (yourVCName *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourVCName"];